# OSX : how to access NAS files in Java

Tags: java, macos, nas

My Environment is OSX BIG SUR.

For space reasons, I need to move files from my Hard disk  to a NAS (on my local network).
The current applications accessing these files (en read mode)  were developed in Java.
I suppose I should use  a Mount command in   programs with the SMB protocol, but how to do this without be prompted  for password with the SUDO command ?
So I'm looking for some examples.

Comment: While the initial reason comes from programming, this question seems to be general computer usage question (https://superuser.com), a Mac question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or maybe even a "server" question (https://serverfault.com/, but I doubt it). [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329392/how-to-escape-password-for-smb-mount) or [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/367950/secure-way-to-mount-a-password-protected-cifs-share-in-mac) might lead you towards the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few ways to go:

### Have java execute the smb mount command

This is a walking disaster; you don't want your java process to gain root privileges to do this.

### Have java be an smb client

Possible... use [JCifs-ng](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng). The docs are lacking, and this would have been a *lot* simpler if it had integrated into the new files / filesystem API, but it doesn't. You'll have some coding to do.

### Learn sysops

All you really need is for the OS to have that samba share mounted someplace and then, to your java process, it's all just files on a filesystem.  Don't make the smb mount happen in java, ensure it's already set up before your java process even starts.